# Одинаковые классы в java

Tags: java

Есть класс `Date date1` и есть класс `Date date2`. Вожможно ли сделать так, чтобы эти класс были полностью одинаковыми **кроме ссылок**? Если мы напишим так `Date date2=date1`, то ссылки будут одинаковыми и при изменении одного будет менятся и другой, а этого как раз не нужно.

Comment: это называется одинаковые **экземпляры** класса. А класс тут не просто одинаковый, а тот же самый

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, это ***экземпляры*** класса `Date`. Во-вторых, у этого класса есть метод [`clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#clone--):

```
//longDate - миллисекунды, прошедшие с 1 января, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
Date date1 = new Date(longDate);
Date date2 = date1.clone();
//Теперь date1 равен date2
```

Comment: повезло, что clone() уже готовенький есть :)

Comment: Спасибо больше!